# Argument 2 passed to array_sort() must be callable, string given

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, laravel

I have the following arrays:

```
  array (size=3)
    0 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 18
        'class' => string 'VIP' (length=3)
        'fee' => float 20
    1 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 19
        'class' => string 'VVIP' (length=4)
        'fee' => float 50
    2 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 20
        'class' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
        'fee' => float 5

  array (size=3)
    0 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 19
        'class' => string 'VVIP' (length=4)
        'fee' => int 50
    1 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 18
        'class' => string 'VIP' (length=3)
        'fee' => int 20
    2 => 
      array (size=3)
        'id' => int 20
        'class' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
        'fee' => int 5
```

Now i am trying to sort them both using `array_sort` in **ascending order** using the `id`.:

```
$array_1 = array_sort($array_1, 'id', SORT_ASC);
$array_2 = array_sort($array_2, 'id', SORT_ASC);
```

However i keep getting the following error:

> Argument 2 passed to array_sort() must be callable, string given

Comment: Alright,thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of [`array_sort`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-sort) should be a closure, not a string:

```
$array_1 = array_sort( $array_1, function($value){
    return $value['id'];
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for your help. :) I was following the docs, wasn't like this there.